# Arrow keys don't work in SSH

Tags: ssh, keyboard, cursor

I'm using SSH host with Ubuntu 16.04. When I use it i can't use in command line arrow keys for moving cursor (^[[D ^[[C) and using previously used commands (^[[A ^[[B), but when I use nano i can do it. How can I fix it?

Comment: What are the outputs of `echo $SHELL` and `echo $0` when you log in via SSH

Comment: /bin/sh & -sh



.

Comment: So it's probably just a matter of changing the remote user's login shell

Answer (score 0):

Yeah sometimes when we are using text editors like nano and vim even we get exit of that the app runs in background and stops the cmd line functionality so you can't use arrow keys to search for previous history

so just gave **reset** cmd which reset the tab and gave you access back to history again

Comment: Nothing changed.